# Elasticsearch - Conditional nested fetching

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index mapping:

```
{
  "dev.directory.3" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "profile" : {
        "properties" : {
          "email" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "events" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with data:

```
"hits" : [ {
    "_index" : "dev.directory.3",
    "_type" : "profile",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "email" : "test@dummy.com",
      "events" : [ 
      {
        "id" : 111,
        "name" : "ABC",
      },
      {
        "id" : 222,
        "name" : "DEF",
      } 
      ],
    }
}]
```

I'd like to filter only matched nested elements instead of returning all `events` array - is this possible in ES?

Example query:

```
{
      "nested" : {
          "path" : "events",
          "query" : {
              "bool" : {
                  "filter" : [
                    { "match" : { "events.id" : 222 } },
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Eg. If I query for events.id=222 there should be only single element on the result list returned.

What strategy for would be the best to achieve this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) to only get the nested records which matched the query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "events",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "events.id": 222
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  },
  "_source": false
}
```

I am also excluding the source to get **only** nested hits